# Rect disappears when changing the coordinates

Tags: java, android, canvas, ondraw, rect

i try to solve the problem of my disappear rect. I draw a rect of the canvas it works fine but if i change the coordinates from this rect to the bottom side its disapper from the screen.

These code show my rect:

```
public class GameView extends View {


    private Paint paint;
    private Rect recco;
    private GameObject ball;
    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initGame(context);
    }

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initGame(context);
    }

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initGame(context);
    }

    public void initGame(Context context){
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        //ball = new GameObject(context);
        recco = new Rect(0,100,200,200); // top left coordinates
        //ball.setSprite(R.drawable.menu_background);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        canvas.drawRect(recco, paint);
       // ball.render(canvas);
    }
}
```

[image]

and now i changed the coordinates to X = 0 and Y = 400 it will be disappear

```
 public void initGame(Context context){
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    //ball = new GameObject(context);
    recco = new Rect(0,400,200,200);
    //ball.setSprite(R.drawable.menu_background);
}
```

[image]